# Initial time as parameter in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I need a help with the function ParametricNDSolve. My goal is solve the equation 
\begin{array}
&&\dot{x}(t) = y(t) \\
&\dot{y}(t) = x(t)-1-\varepsilon Cos(\omega t) \\
&x(t_0) = x_0\\
&y(t_0) = y_0
\end{array}
where, $x_0,y_0,t_0$ and $\varepsilon$ are parametres that i wish to adjust. The option i chose was the function ParametricNDSolve. So, to solve that equation the function became

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t],
y'[t] == x[t] - 1 - \[Epsilon] Cos[5 t], x[t0] == x0 ,
y[t0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {t0, x0, y0, \[Epsilon]}]
```

Until here no problem. But, when I try to plot

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[0, 0, y0, 0][t] /. sol, {y0, -1, 1, .1}]], {t,0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Mathematica returns this mensagem

```
ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable x. >>
```

I know that the problem is in parameter $t_0$, because when I run this functions with $t_0 = 0$ no problem apperars.

Someone has some ideia what is going on? Some sugestion to solve this problem?

Sorry about my english.

Comment: You may change the `t0` dependency by a phase in the Cosine

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, `ParametricNDSolve` cannot handle `x[t0]` or `y[t0]` when `t0` is a parameter.  A work-around is to shift time to begin at `t0`, in which case the code becomes,

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], 
    y'[t] == x[t] - 1 - ϵ Cos[5 (t + t0)], x[0] == x0, 
    y[0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, -t0, -t0 + 10}, {t0, x0, y0, ϵ}]
```

which works fine.  This does seem like a Mathematica shortcoming, however.

[image]

Comment: I think in general the usage would be `y[t0, x0, y0, ϵ][t - y0] /. sol`, and one would want to integrate over `{t, -t0, -t0 + 10}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2  I have made the correction.  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. :)  (+1) -- oops, I meant `y[t0, x0, y0, ϵ][t - t0] /. sol`.  [Typo with `y0` in place of `t0`.]

Answer (score 8):

Given that `ParametricNDSolve` does not handle this case, one can revert to the old way.  Uncomment the memoization if desired; it will speed things up if `sol` is called multiple times with the same parameters.

```
Clear[sol];
sol[t0_, x0_, y0_, ϵ_] :=
 (*sol[t0, x0, y0, ϵ] =*)
  NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t] - 1 - ϵ Cos[5 t], 
   x[t0] == x0, y[t0] == y0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Here's a different plot to show that the dependence on `t` and `t0` is as desired:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[t] /. sol[t0, 0, 1, 0], {t0, -1, 1, .2}]],
 {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> {None, {1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]