# 3D Plot using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting

I want to make a 3D plot using the following code. Please help.

```
a = 0.5;
d = 1.0;
Ha = 3.0;
x = 0.5;
q = 1.0;
alp = 0.1;
bt = 2.0;
m = 5.0;
F = q*Exp[-alp*c];
h = (1 - a*Cos[3.14*(x - c)]*Cos[3.14*(x - c)]);
sols = ParametricNDSolve[{y''''[t] == 
    Ha^2 y''[t] - (m*m*m*bt*Sinh[m*t]/Cosh[m*h]), y''[0] == 0, 
   y[0] == 0, y'[h] == 0, y[h] == F}, y, {t, 0, h}, {c}]
Plot3D[Evaluate[y'[t] /. sols], {t, 0, h}, {c, 0, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76692/initial-time-as-parameter-in-parametricndsolve)

```
a = 0.5;
d = 1.0;
Ha = 3.0;
x = 0.5;
q = 1.0;
alp = 0.1;
bt = 2.0;
m = 5.0;
F = q*Exp[-alp*c];
h = (1 - a*Cos[3.14*(x - c)]*Cos[3.14*(x - c)]);
```

You wrote `c` is range `0..2` then: `h` is: `Max[(1 - a*Cos[Pi*(x - #)]*Cos[Pi*(x - #)])] & /@ Range[0, 2]` is 1,and for that I set up a  `t=(0..1)`.

```
sol[c_] := 
NDSolve[{y''''[t] == Ha^2 y''[t] - (m*m*m*bt*Sinh[m*t]/Cosh[m*h]), 
y''[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[h] == 0, y[h] == F}, y, {t, 0, 1}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[y'[t] /. sol[c], {c, 0, 2, .1}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 3}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y'[t] /. sol[c], {c, 0, 2, 1/4}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 3}}, 
PlotLabels -> {"c=0", "c=1/4", "c=1/2", "c=3/4", "c=1", "c=5/4", 
"c=3/2", "c=7/4", "c=2"}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y'[t]"}]
```

[image]

```
 ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[Evaluate[Table[{c, t, (y'[t] /.sol[c])[[1]]}, {c, 0, 2, 1/20}]], {t, 0, 
 1, 1/20}]], 3], AxesLabel -> {c, t},PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help. But the "PlotLabels" option does not work in my MATHEMATICA 10.0. It becomes Red when I write "PlotLabels". But If I replaced it by "PlotLabel", then the labels appear at the top of the figure in a single row. May I know, how to fix it?

Comment: @BiswajitMallick. Use: `Plot[Evaluate[Table[y'[t] /. sol[c], {c, 0, 2, 1/4}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-2, 3}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"c=0", "c=1/4", "c=1/2", "c=3/4", "c=1", "c=5/4", 
   "c=3/2", "c=7/4", "c=2"}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y'[t]"}]` works in MMA 10.2.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mariusz Iwaniuk.

Comment: Could you kindly have a look on my last question. I have to make a contour plot. @Mariusz Iwaniuk

Comment: @BiswajitMallick  I'm don't see any question? ,contour plot?

Comment: I posted a new question a few minutes ago. Please I need a last favour from you. I am new in the world of Mathematica. Hope you will understand my situation.

Comment: @BiswajitMallick. Do not forget to vote for my correct answers.

Comment: Yes. Ofcourse. If you don't mind .. May I know how to vote a answer?

Comment: @BiswajitMallick .I mean, accept my answer.Thanks

Comment: Would you like to have a look on my new question in which I want to solve a fourth order ode using NDSolve.

Answer (score 2):

`DSolve` is able to find an analytical solution to your ode,

```
sol = DSolve[{y''''[t] == Ha^2 y''[t] - (m*m*m*bt*Sinh[m*t]/Cosh[m*h]), y''[0] == 0, 
    y[0] == 0, y'[h] == 0, y[h] == F}, y, t];

Dy = D[y[t] /. sol, t];

Plot3D[Dy, {t, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I have to use NDSolve only due to the complexity of my original problem.