# ParametricNDSolve can't find initial value

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

If I do an `NDSolve` of an IVP directly, everything works:

```
x[.5] /. NDSolve[{x[0] == 0, x'[t] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 1}][[1]]
```

But if I try to parametrise it, it doesn't

```
x[0][.5] /. ParametricNDSolve[{x[T] == 0, x'[t] == 1}, x, {t, T, T+1}, {T}][[1]]
```

I receive a `ParametricNDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable x.` error. I cannot see what I'm doing wrong!? I guess this use of the parameter just isn't allowed?

Answer (score 3):

`ParametricNDSolve` is not helpful in such [cases](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76692/initial-time-as-parameter-in-parametricndsolve). However, you can use `NDSolve` with a `SetDelay`,

```
sol[T_] := NDSolve[{x[T] == 0, x'[t] == 1}, x, {t, T, T + 1}];

yfun = First[x /. sol[0]];

yfun[0.5]
```

> 0.5