# Minimize a function which is a result of numerically solving a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I’m new here and also a beginner with Mathematica.

My problem:

I want to minimize a function which is a result of solving an ODE with `NDSolve`. The ODE is second order, linear, with variable coefficients.
The functions describing the variable coefficients are dependent on T:

```
a[T_?NumericQ] := 7027.84123 Exp[-0.05520*T] + 422.14995 Exp[-0.00026*T];
b[T_?NumericQ] := (836676.69065)*T^(-3.71263) + (1.04101); 
c[T_?NumericQ] := 0.06854*T - 2.84655;
```

The ODE looks like:

```
ODE[x_] := A*D[a[T[x]]*T'[x], x] - p*b[T[x]]*T'[x] + C*c[T[x]] == 0
```

The boundary conditions for the ODE:

```
BC1 : = T[0.0] == T1;
BC2 := T[Length] == T2;
```

`A, C, T1, T2` are constants.

And `p` should actually be a function which consists of a value which is the result of the solution of the ODE and a parameter which can be influenced by the optimization process, for example like that:

```
p := T'[0.0] + optimizationParameter1
```

The objective function of the optimization which should be minimized is:

```
ObjectFunc := D*T'[0.0] + E*optimizationParameter1
```

`D` and `E` are constants again.

So I'm trying to combine the solution of the ODE (done by `NDSolve`) with the optimization process (done by `NMinimze`). But I don't really know how to do that. I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
TempSolution = 
  NDSolve[
    {ODE[x], BC1, BC2}, T, {x, 0.0, Length}, 
    Method -> 
      {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {T[0.0] == T1, T'[0] == 600}}]

Tsolution[x_] := T[x] /. TempSolution

optfunction[Length_?NumericQ] := 
  ObjectFunc /. 
    First @ 
      NDSolve[
        {ODE[x], BC1, BC2}, T, {x, 0.0, Length}, 
        Method -> 
          {"Shooting", 
           "StartingInitialConditions" -> {T[0.0] == T1, T'[0] == 600}}]

resultOptimization = 
  NMinimize[{optfunction[Length], Length > 0, Length < 2.0}, Length]
```

It is important to know, that `optimizationParameter1` and also the border of the ODE, `Length`, should be a parameter which can be influenced by the optimization in order to minimize the objective function.

I hope my problem is clear and maybe someone can help me with it. Don't hesitate to ask in case of understanding problems and thanks a lot in advance.

**Edited equations:**

```
 ODE[x_] := (7.854*10^(-5))*D[a[T[x]]*T'[x],x] - p*(b[T[x]]*1000)*T'[x] + (12.732)*c[T[x]] == 00
```

The boundary conditions:

```
BC1 := T[0.0] == 77;
BC2[lopt_] := T[lopt] == 300;
```

Function p:

```
p := 2.02*10^(-7)*T'[0.0] + optimizationParameter1
```

The objective function:

```
objectfunc := (1000*769.2)*(2.02*10^(-7)*T'[0.0]) + (1000*195.9)*optimizationParameter1
```

Actually, I roughly know the results of the optimization because I did this already with another programm. Results from this programm:

```
lopt = 0.5439
p =  2.57*10^(-4) = 3.86*10^(-5) + 2.18*10^(-4)
optimizationParameter1 = 2.18*10^(-4)
```

And using this results as fix values in the ODE, I can solve the ODE with NDSolve. But I also want to do the optimization with Mathematica and that doesn't work yet.
Thanks in advance for your help.

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

**Update to my question:**

I still have the problem that I'm not able to solve this combined problem of a differential equation and an optimization problem. I already have some "rough" solutions produced by another program for this problem, but I have to realize and solve this also in Mathematica. And therefore, I hope to find some help to do that because I’m a beginner with Mathematica.

According to your advices, I changed the differential equation and removed the optimization parameter from the boundary conditions. This optimization parameter is now only part of the actual differential equation. Now, the code looks like:

```
a[T_?NumericQ] := 7027.84123 Exp[-0.05520*T] + 422.14995 Exp[-0.00026*T];
b[T_?NumericQ] := (836676.69065)*T^(-3.71263) + (1.04101);
c[T_?NumericQ] := 0.06854*T - 2.84655;
lfix = 0.3528;
m = 0.4212/(3600);
```

The differential equation:

```
ODE[x_] := D[a[T[x]] * optimizationParameterA * T'[x], x] - 
 m * (b[T[x]] * 1000) * T'[x] + (1/1000) * 
 c[T[x]] * (1/optimizationParameterA) == 00
```

The boundary conditions (now constant):

```
BC1 := T[0.0] == 77.4;
BC2 := T[lfix] == 300;
```

The value which should be minimized:

```
minimizationValue := (optimizationParameterA*a[T[0.0]]*T'[0.0]);
```

And the optimization:

```
Clear[objectivefunction];

 objectivefunction[optimizationParameterA_ ?NumericQ] := minimizationValue /. First @ NDSolve[{ODE[x], BC1, BC2}, T, {x, 0.0, lfix}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {T[0.0] == 77.4, 
       T'[0.0] == 590}} ];
```

And the optimization call:

```
callOptimization = NMinimize[{objectivefunction[optimizationParameterA], optimizationParameterA > 0.0, optimizationParameterA < ((\[Pi]*(5*0.01)^2)/4)}, optimizationParameterA}, Method -> "NelderMead", AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 10, MaxIterations -> 10000]
```

This can be solved by Mathematica and I get an optimum:

> {23.44862779, {optimizationParameterA -> 0.00007838022233}}

But now, I have the problem that I have ro replace the constant value ***m*** in the differential equation. Because ***m*** is actually a result of the equation, like that:

```
m := (optimizationParameterA*a[T[0.0]]*T'[0.0]) / (199180)
```

And just replacing **m** in the differential equation with this expression doesn't work.
I really hope that someone can help me with this problem to be able to do this optimization with Mathematica.
Thanks you very much in advance and best regards.

Comment: Your ode and bc depend on some parameter, which you want to otimize. Therefor it is necessary to use ParametricNDSolve instead of NDSolve.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't believe that `ParametricNDSolve` can be used here.  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76692

Comment: One problem is that `BC2` depends on the parameter but is not defined in terms of it: `BC2[length_] := T[length] == T2;` and change how it is called in `NDSolve`. Another thing is that `Length` is a built-in function, so maybe change it to `length`.  Generally it's good to avoid starting your own variable names with a capital.

Comment: @Michael E2: In my comment  I intended to focus that usually the optimization-parameters have to be explicitely defined in the function call. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Note also that `C` is a protected symbol used for integration constants and other parametrized solutions, `D` is the differentiation operator (see `ObjectFunc`) and `E` is the base of the natural exponential/logarithm functions. Best avoid initial capitals, as a said. -- Finally, to get people to try out their ideas, it would be good to have example numerical values for the constants.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your fast reply. I worked in your suggestions and also added numerical values for the constants, so now, you can try out (see above in the edited post). Thanks a lot